# Why is $f(x) = \frac{x^{n-1}}{(1+x^{2})^{k}}$ Lebesgue-integrable over $(0,\infty)$ for all $k > \frac{n}{2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I want to show that, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and for all $k > \frac{n}{2}$
$$f(x) = \frac{x^{n-1}}{(1+x^{2})^{k}}$$

is Lebesgue-integrable over $X = (0,\infty)$. I was able to show that $f(x)$ is Lebesgue-integrable over all $(0,s)$ where $s>0$. However, I couldn't find a proof for the desired set. I was trying to find a Lebesgue-integrable function $g$ such that $0\le f \le g$ so
$$\int_{X} f dm_1 \le \int_{X} g dm_1 < +\infty$$

Therefore, f is Lebesgue-integrable. But all of my attempts were unsuccessful :'c.

Can you give me a hint o tell me if I am wrong?

Comment: I'm happy to expand upon my answer if the hint doesn't get you there.  By the way, your technique was right.  I simply pointed out what $ g $ will work.  I also tried to give you a sense of the intuition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really want to split the interval into $ [0, 1] $ and $ [1, \infty] $.  It's easy to see that $ f $ is integrable on $ [0,1] $ because it's bounded.  For $ [1, \infty] $, find a constant $ C $ such that you can compare $ f(x) $ to $ C x^{n-1-2k} $.  If this seems non-intuitive to you consider my intuition: "for large values of $ x $, the $ + 1 $ becomes insignificant."

Comment: C = 1 is useful since $x^2 < 1+x^2$ implies $\frac{(x^{n-1})}{(1+x^{2})^{k}} < \frac{x^{n-1}}{x^{2k}}$. The rest of the proof is easier by using $k > \frac{n}{2}$. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome.  Yeah, you don't even need the $ C $ I don't know why I wrote that, but I'm very glad you figured it out.